# How to calculate: $ \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} (e^{t^2}-1)dt}{{\int_{0}^{x^2} \sin(t)dt}} $

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

How do I calculate the follwing Limit:

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} (e^{t^2}-1)dt}{{\int_{0}^{x^2} \sin(t)dt}} $$

I have been solving an exam from my University's collection of previous exams, and in one of them, there wasn't an official solution, but one taken from a student's exam paper, and I couldn't understand the transition in first line.

here is a picture that I posted in Imgur ( sorry I don't have enough reputation to post pictures here so I hope u understand)

[image]

I thought about the Fundamental Theory of Calculus, because the functions integrable, then using lHopital's rule to find the limit, but I didn't get how to apply the Fundamental Thoery of Calculus here.

any kind of help would be appreciated:) !!

Comment: l'Hôpital's rule might work here.

Comment: Not posting pictures would be even better. About the formula, please replace "inner" $x$s by anything else. About the question, please add your thoughts, at present there are none.

Comment: sorry, I was still editing the post.

Comment: Try Taylor series for numerator and denominator; long division then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neither the formula in the post nor in the picture makes sense. I assume you are looking for

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} (e^{t^2}-1)\mathrm{d}t}{{\int_{0}^{x^2} \sin(t)\mathrm{d}t}} $$

It's obvious that both terms individually go to zero, thus, you can apply L'Hospital's rule (from your question I take, you might want to look up Leibniz' rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: so this has nothing to do with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? or there is a relation between two things?

Comment: It has everything to do with fundamental theorem. It's merely the application of the fundamental theorem to the case where the integral boundaries depend on the variable with respect to which you are derivating

Answer (score 2):

Starting from user1337's answer, consider $$A=\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{2x\sin(x^2)}$$ when $x$ is small.

Now use Taylor expansions $$e^y=1+y+\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ $$\sin(y)=y-\frac{y^3}{6}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ and replace $y$ by $x^2$ so $$A=\frac{x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+\cdots}{2x\Big(x^2-\frac{x^6}{6} +\cdots\Big)}=\frac{x^2\Big(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots\Big)}{2x^3\Big(1-\frac{x^4}{6} +\cdots\Big)}=\frac 1 {2x} \times\frac{1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots}{1-\frac{x^4}{6} +\cdots}$$ When $x\to 0$, the last term goes to $1$ and then $A$ behaves as $\frac 1x$; so the limit.

Answer (score 1):

As your limit involves the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ we examine the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{x} (e^{t^2}-1)dt}{\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{x^2} \sin (t) dt}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x^2}-1}{2x\sin(x^2)}.$$

Where we have applied the fundamental theorem of calculus to get the RHS. Using l'Hôpital's rule a second time seems to give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Already typing up the solution before I saw the solution of user1337.

So from where he stopped, I continue...

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x^2}-1}{2x\sin(x^2)}=
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2xe^{x^2}}{4x^2\cos(x^2)+2\sin(x^2)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4x^2e^{x^2}+2e^{x^2}}{8x\cos(x^2)-8x^3\sin{x^2}+4x\cos(x^2)}=\frac{2}{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor-Maclaurin expansions $\exp(u) = 1 + u + o(u)$ and $\sin(u)=u + o(u)$ yield, as $x$ tends to $0^+$,
$$
\int_0^x (e^{t^2}-1)dt \sim\int_0^xt^2dt = \frac{x^3}{3}
$$

$$
\int_0^{x^2} \sin(t)dt\sim\int_0^{x^2}tdt = \frac{x^4}{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\int_0^x (e^{t^2}-1)dt}{\int_0^{x^2} \sin(t)dt} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{2}{3x} = +\infty.
$$